# Which basis 2-form elements represent positive traversals in Minkowski 4-space?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions

I'm certain some of this relies on arbitrary choice, for even in Euclidean 3-space, there is no *a priori* preferred choice of left versus right hand coordinates.  In fact according to Einstein:

> There are thus two kinds of Cartesian systems which are designated as
> "right-handed" and "left-handed" systems. The difference between these is
> familiar to every physicist and engineer. It is interesting to note that these
> two kinds of systems cannot be defined geometrically, but only the contrast
> between them. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/36276/36276-pdf.pdf page 10, footnote.

One interpretation I have seen for a 2-form basis element $dx^{\alpha}\wedge dx^{\beta}$ is as a traversal around a differential two-surface, first along $dx^{\alpha}$ then along $dx^{\beta}$ and continuing to complete the circuit.  In Euclidean 3-space represented using right-handed rectangular Cartesian coordinates the positive traversals are $dx\wedge dy,$ $dy\wedge dz$ and $dz\wedge dx.$  Since the wedge and cross products are synonymous in this context we can express the oriented surface elements as $dx\wedge dy=dz,$ etc.  Thus $dy\wedge dx=-dz$ would represent a negative traversal.

In Minkowski 4-space we have the same parity, $dx^{\alpha}\wedge dx^{\beta}=-dx^{\beta}\wedge dx^{\alpha}$.  But now we encounter a number of complicating factors.  First of all, a 2-surface traversal determines a 2-space orthogonal complement which must be spanned by two basis 1-forms, or by a basis 2-from which is linearly independent of the first basis 2-form.

There is also a question of how the Minkowski metric $\{-,+,+,+\}$ (per MTW) influences the algebraic sign of a traversal.  I will assume that a positive traversal associates with a positively oriented complementary basis two-form.

An example of the use of a two-form basis is in the expression given in Box 4.1 A.2 of MTW for the ***Faraday*** two-form:

$$\mathbf{F}=-E_{x}dt\wedge dx-E_{y}dt\wedge dy-E_{z}dt\wedge dz$$

$$+B_{x}dy\wedge dz+B_{y}dz\wedge dx+B_{z}dx\wedge dy.$$

**Is it possible to consistently identify which basis 2-forms represent positive traversals?  Is there an established convention?  If so what is it?**

I will leave the question of Hodge duality of basis 2-forms for the future, unless it is essential to addressing the current question.

As an example in which oriented traversals arise see Box 15.1 of MTW.  I may be able to extract a satisfactory answer by carefully re-reading the first 400 pages.  But I don't recall MTW giving a simple listing of the positively oriented two-surfaces of spacetime. The discussion of Hodge duals makes it more difficult to sort this out.

[image]

Comment: Wedge products aren’t the same as cross products. There is no justification for considering “traversals” to be positive or negative.

Comment: Hmmm.  That's how Dr.  Wheeler presented 2-froms back in the 1980s at Robert Lee Moore, Hall of UT Austin.

Comment: A cross product doesn’t even exist in four dimensions.

Comment: Please read what I wrote more carefully.